# I am not able get content-disposition on client

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am trying to retrieve .xlsx file, which is generated in the backend (spring boot). On frontend I retrieve header, which include *content-disposition* as you can see. But I cannot get access to the header content disposition.

As you can see on the print bellow, Content disposition is not present in the headers, it is present in XHR response headers.
**Xhr response**
[image: XHR response]
**console.log**
[image: console log]

I enable cors policy on backed,

```
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

and get content-disposition on client

```
 public static downloadFile(data: any, untilDestroyed$: DestroyService, toasterService?: ToastrService) {
    const openInWindow = data.body.type === 'application/pdf';
    console.log(data);

    const dispositionHeader = data.headers.get('Content-Disposition'); // there is problem, value is not possible get
    const blob = new Blob([data.body], {type: data.body.type});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ticket can help you : [Unable to view 'Content-Disposition' headers in Angular4 GET response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892875/unable-to-view-content-disposition-headers-in-angular4-get-response/45920390)

```
    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
    corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Content-Disposition, 
    Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    corsFilter.setExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" response header is used to instruct a server and specify which response headers are accessible to scripts executed within a browser, particularly in response to a cross-origin request.

In order to allow custom headers to be accessed in browser scripts, server (spring boot backend in your case) has to specify such headers explicitly.

You can do this in CorsFilter or if you need this for specific responses, then by explicitly specifying as below.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
allowedHeaders.add("Content-Disposition");
headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(allowedHeaders);
```

[Access-Control-Expose-Headers on MDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20230928175927/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)